# What is a nice self studying pre algebra and algebra 1 book for a 15 year old with really rusty math skills?

Tags: reference-request

I am currently 15 years old and I have really really rusty math skills especially algebra. My algebra test score is usually around 45% and I am going into the 10th grade next year. I have two months of holidays coming up and i want to improve me algebra skill. So does anybody have any recommendations for a good book in pre Algebra and algebra 1. The book has to contain solutions and a lot of questions.

Comment: I wish people would stop down voting questions like these. I get that they are not clear cut math questions, but is this really too broad of a question to answer? The OP gave plenty of details for some of you math instructors out there to be able to help her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find a PDF book which includes exercises [here](http://www.math10.ca/index.php). Keep in mind that this pertains to British Columbia, Canada, which may have a different curriculum than your part of the planet.

For online tutorials and exercises, check out [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/).

All the Best!

Comment: The thing I have checked out khan academy but I seem to find textbooks or e books more useful than videos. And I also have a limited internet limit of 2gb so watching videos from khan academy will take up a lot of Internet usage.

Comment: I'd check out the other link then. Good idea to review Algebra.

Comment: I have taken a look at the PDF link u sent me and I think I need something that can teach me math using examples and has excersies in it. Your book contains excersies but it doesn't contain a lot of examples for a beginner.

Comment: There are other notes on that page as well with worked examples.